# Sharepoint EventReceiver Singleton for one thread

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, event-receivers

I would like to create singleton patter in *Sharepoint* *EventReciever*. The singleton have to be unique for every run of EventReceiver (I dont want to share data between ed and ing function - this is not trget).

I would like to load some settings data form custom list to my singleton instance. but after end of `itemAdding\ItemUpdated`... i would like to forgot all data and in next run load it all back (data can be updated and i dont want to hold old information).

*Static* variable in some singleton class is not good approach (this variable will be shared between many items updating and will never refresh its content - I think only server restart clear this data). In standard web requests I used for this purpose `HTTPContext.Items`, is in Sharepoint `EventReceiver` possibility to use something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple approach you can use, but this will create a singleton for the thread (as you asked), leading to data shared accros all ER run in the same thread (e.g. `ItemAdding` **and** *async* `ItemAdded`). Is this a problem?

Use a `LocalDataStoreSlot`:

```
private static System.LocalDataStoreSlot m_theDataSlot;
private static object m_theDataSlotLockObject = new object();
private static void EnsureTheDataSlot()
{
  if (m_theDataSlot == null)
  {
    lock (m_theDataSlotLockObject)
    {
      // Will be done only once in the entire app life
      // The slot is created once for the app, but it can then stores
      // one piece of data per thread
      if (m_theDataSlot == null)
        m_theDataSlot = System.Threading.Thread.AllocateDataSlot();
    }
  }
}

private static string TheData
{
  get
  {
    // Ensures the thread is "theData-aware"
    EnsureTheDataSlot();

    // Retrieves data for the current thread
    object data = System.Threading.Thread.GetData(m_theDataSlot);
    if (data != null)
      return data.ToString();
    else
      return "";
  }
  set
  {
    // Ensures the thread is "theData-aware"
    EnsureTheDataSlot();

    // Sets data for the current thread
    System.Threading.Thread.SetData(m_theDataSlot, value);
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, thans you. this looks fine. I implemented it now and i will test it tomorow.